# Calling an unmanaged library function that takes a reference to a pointer

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke, marshalling, dllimport

Let's say we have a C++ function with the following prototype:

```
int myFunction(int someNumber, int &arraySize, signed char *&array)
// Extra function to free allocated memory:
int freePointer(void* myPointer)
```

This function takes some number, and creates an array depending on that number. So we pass a number and get an array. What is the best way to call it in C#?

**My first approach:**

```
[DllImport(...)]
internal static int myFunction(int someNumber, out int arraySize, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 1)] out byte[] array)

// ...

byte[] myArray;
int discard;
int myNumber = 100;

myFunction(myNumber, discard, myArray);
```

But the problem is, I need to free the memory allocated by the unmanaged library, and I don't know how to pass the address of `myArray` to `freePointer()`. And also, I don't know if the address of `myArray` is equal to the address of the array created by the unmanaged library.

And then **my second approach** was:

```
[DllImport(...)]
internal static int myFunction(int someNumber, out int arraySize, out IntPtr array)

// ...

byte[] myArray;
int myArraySize
IntPtr pointerToArray;
int myNumber = 100;

myFunction(myNumber, myArraySize, pointerToArray);

Marshal.Copy(pointerToArray, myArray, 0, myArraySize);
FreePointerHandler(pointerToArray.ToPointer());
```

But again, I'm not sure if I'm doing it right by sending the address of the `IntPtr` using the method `.ToPointer()`.

I don't want to introduce memory leaks, what would you suggest doing? (Without using unsafe code.)

**Edit:** Should I use `ref` rather than `out`, as the parameter is a reference to a pointer?

Comment: Yes, second way is correct.  Hard to believe you haven't tried it.  Or tested it by calling this a million times.  What's the hang-up?

Comment: I would expose this as C rather than C++. `char *&array` will be odd to handle in C# I think. `char **array` would be a lot easier.

Comment: @Hans I used it and it seemed to work, but I was afraid that I may introduce some memory leaks somehow even though it seemed to work. How can I test if I've introduced memory leaks or not? I mean to be sure that all the memory allocated by the unmanaged function is cleaned up afterwards?

Comment: That's why you test it by calling it a million times.  If there's a leak then you'll find out about it.

Comment: @leppie - char*& is just a C++ syntax goodie, it is actually a char**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your second approach looks about right to me. Where you have:

```
FreePointerHandler(pointerToArray.ToPointer());
```

I think you can just:

```
FreePointerHandler(pointerToArray);
```

I'm writing a test and will post an edit.

#### `ref` vs. `out`

As far as `ref` vs. `out`, this doesn't map exactly to C++ reference. When C# call C#, an `out` parameter is required to be set by the called function. With an an interop call this can't be enforced, for documentation value, I prefer `out` in this case.

#### The real problem

The real problem is if you don't have experience with .Net pinvoke, it's hard to have confidence when calling functions without any immediate, visible side effects.

@Hans Passant recommended "test it by calling it a million times" in order to make any memory leak apparent. While this approach is probably simplest in this case, it doesn't generalize to the case where there's not an associated memory resource and if it fails it doesn't give any additional information. I prefer to debug through the pinvoke call if I have the source code for the .dll or to write a mock API implementation if I don't. That way when you're trying out a new pinvoke feature you can see exactly what's going on. And if there's a problem, tracing in the debugger can help you see where you went wrong.

#### A full pinvoke example

Here's a full example based on the original question. The return values were not documented, nor the details of myFunction. The example just fills an allocated array of length 3 with (0, 1, 2).

Here's the DLL's header file:

```
// testlib.h

#ifdef TESTLIB_EXPORTS
#define TESTLIB_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define TESTLIB_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

extern "C" {
    TESTLIB_API int myFunction(int someNumber, int &arraySize, signed char *&array);
    TESTLIB_API int freePointer(void* myPointer);
}
```

The .DLL's .cpp source file:

```
// testlib.cpp : Defines the exported functions for the DLL application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "testlib.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


TESTLIB_API int myFunction(int someNumber, int &arraySize, signed char *&array)
{
    #ifdef _DEBUG
        cout << "myFunction enter " << someNumber << ", " << arraySize << ", 0x"  << &array << endl;
    #endif
    arraySize = 3;

    array = (signed char*)malloc(arraySize);

    #ifdef _DEBUG
        cout << "myFunction array: 0x" << (void *)array << endl;
    #endif

    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; ++i)
    {
        array[i] = i;
    }

    #ifdef _DEBUG
        cout << "myFunction exit " << someNumber << ", " << arraySize << ", 0x"  << &array << endl;
    #endif

    return 0;
}

TESTLIB_API int freePointer(void* myPointer)
{
    #ifdef _DEBUG
        cout << "freePointer: 0x" << myPointer << endl;
    #endif

    free(myPointer);
    return 0;
}
```

The C# source:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace InteropTest
{
    class InteropTest
    {
        [DllImport("testlib.dll")]
        private static extern int myFunction(int someNumber, out int arraySize, out IntPtr array);

        [DllImport("testlib.dll")]
        public static extern int freePointer(IntPtr pointer);

        public static byte[] myFunction(int myNumber)
        {
            int myArraySize;
            IntPtr pointerToArray;
            int iRet = myFunction(myNumber, out myArraySize, out pointerToArray);
            // should check iRet and if needed throw exception

            #if (DEBUG)
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("InteropTest.myFunction myArraySize: {0}", myArraySize);
                Console.WriteLine();
            #endif

            byte[] myArray = new byte[myArraySize];
            Marshal.Copy(pointerToArray, myArray, 0, myArraySize);
            freePointer(pointerToArray);

            #if (DEBUG)
               Console.WriteLine();
            #endif

            return myArray;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            #if (DEBUG)
                Console.WriteLine("Start InteropTest");
                Console.WriteLine();
            #endif
            int myNumber = 123;

            byte[] myArray = myFunction(myNumber);

            for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Length; ++i)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("InteropTest myArray[{0}] = {1}", i, myArray[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The debug build prints status messages. They show `myFunction`'s `array` value is what's passed to `freePointer`.

I've also created an C# interface function for `myFunction`. When a pinvoke call is non trivial, you usually want to work out the details once and encapsulate it into a function for reuse.

Comment: To be able to use `FreePointerHandler(pointerArray)`, I have to change it's DllImport signature from `... FreePointerHandler(void* pointer)` to `... FreePointerHandler(IntPtr pointer)`. Are they equivalent?

Comment: Equivalent? I'm not sure exactly what you mean. They are different, but I think IntPtr is better in this case. An `IntPtr` marshals the same as a `void*`, but `IntPtr` has better support within C#, for example that's what `Marshal.Copy` takes as a param. So I recommend using `FreePointerHandler(IntPtr pointer)`. I'm still working on my test code, I'm having a problem with my environment at the moment.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the update! Unfortunately I don't have the source code of the library. I have tried Hans Passant's method (calling it a million times), and the method works as expected. The problem was, it worked without any problems even when I didn't call the `freePointer` function. I thought that would introduce a memory leak. I didn't understand why it was working fine. Any ideas?

Comment: No idea why you wouldn't see  a memory leak. I don't even have enough information to make a guess. I was  trying to demonstrate how you could test the mechanics of pinvoke without the DLL source by mocking the API.

Comment: I was just wondering if the system was cleaning up the memory that was not freed somehow. I don't know much about C++ and managing memory honestly. Thanks for the answer though.