# calling c++ char* from c# project System.AccessViolationException

Tags: c#, c++, interop

I'm trying to call a c++ library method from a c# project without much success. I always get the same error.

> ```
> System.AccessViolationException: 'Attempted to read or write protected
> memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.'
> ```

The c++ method signature looks like this

```
int __stdcall getErrorMessage(int errorId, char *&errorMessage);
```

I have tried every combination so far but nothing seems to work.

```
[DllImportAttribute("Lib.dll", EntryPoint = "getErrorMessage", 
CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)] 
public static extern int getErrorMessage(int errorId, ref StringBuilder errorMessage);

[DllImportAttribute("Lib.dll", EntryPoint = "getErrorMessage",
CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)] 
public static extern int getErrorMessage(int errorId, ref IntPtr errorMessage);


[DllImportAttribute("Lib.dll", EntryPoint = "getErrorMessage",
CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)] 
public static extern int getErrorMessage(int errorId, IntPtr errorMessage);
```

Any help will be really appreciated.

EDIT

The way Im calling it is as follows

> var ptr = new IntPtr();
>
> var ret = NativeMethods.getErrorMessage(number, ref ptr);

Also there is another call to release the memory once it's done

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: So the getErrorMessage probably allocates some memory and returns a pointer to it in the char*& parameter? In order to properly clean up, you will need to know how this memory is allocated. If it is not one of the allocators suported by the interop layer (e.g. CoTaskMemAlloc), I fear you are out of luck. Of course, you can always write a wrapper lib using C++/CLI.

Comment: There is another method to realease the memory allocated by this call.
The way Im calling it is 
            var ptr = new IntPtr();

            var ret = NativeMethods.getErrorMessage(number, ref ptr);

Comment: Did you see this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14816970/calling-an-unmanaged-library-function-that-takes-a-reference-to-a-pointer

Comment: ref IntPtr is correct, whether you passed a valid number can't be guessed.  It is probably wise to assume you should only ever call it when another function indicated failure.  Send a small repro project to the author of the C++ code so he can debug it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's finally working, the problem happens as Hans Passant mentioned, when we try to query the method with any arbitrary error code.

> Working code.
>
> ```
> var ptr = new IntPtr();
>
> var ret = NativeMethods.getErrorMessage(code, ref ptr);
>
>         if (ptr != IntPtr.Zero)
>         {
>             message = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(ptr);
>             NativeMethods.freePointer(ref ptr);
>         }
> ```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

After you got `IntPtr` you should convert it to `string` using [`PtrToStringAuto`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.ptrtostringauto?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Runtime_InteropServices_Marshal_PtrToStringAuto_System_IntPtr_) Or [`PtrToStringAnsi`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.ptrtostringansi?view=netframework-4.7.2)